# SQL server , We have one column of the data decimal(38,35) truncating when we are using cast and float in sql server

Tags: sql-server

We have one column in sql server where we need to consider the all the digits as it is transaction table.The column data type like decimal(38,35) ,its appending zeroes when in sql server like the value is 1.2369 but its displaying as 1.236900000000000000.. but it can be restricted by using float and cast like 
"**select cast(cast('1.2369'as decimal(38,35))as float)**" it will truncate all the zeroes but the real question is when we use the same expression for the bigger decimal value like 1.236597879646479444896645 its truncate the trailing values,considering only up-to scale of 15 digits,if anybody finds the logic for this one please help me .Thank you and 
Note :The values are always dynamic.

Comment: If it's a number, why do you care about the *default formatting* applied by management studio? Apply whatever formatting you like *in your presentation layer*.

Comment: Can you please more precise?

Comment: In Mathematics 1.2369 = 1.236900000000000000 . Why do you care about 0s?

Comment: Because it occupies the space and when we do mathematical operations time taking will be more and considered to be its bad data not the quality one.

Comment: @Raghubenten - it occupies space *when you convert it to a string and print it*. It's not occupying space (well not appreciably) in the *numeric data type*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format a `DECIMAL(38,35)` without insignificant zeroes, use an explicit  `FORMAT` string, e.g.

```
SELECT FORMAT(1.23690000000000000, '0.' + REPLICATE('#', 35))
```

gives `1.2369` (SQL Server 2012 and up). Note, however, that the resulting type is a string, not a number, and so this should only ever be done as the final step (and only if your client software isn't smart enough to format the values on its own). While you're calculating with it, there is either no need to cut off digits, or else you need to be explicit about it by converting to the appropriate `DECIMAL` (e.g. `1.2369` fits in a `DECIMAL(5, 4)`). SQL Server can't do this automatically because it doesn't know what kind of precision you're going for in your calculations, but it is definitely something you must take into account, because combining `DECIMAL`s of different scale and precisions can give unexpected results when you're close to the edge.

Answer (score 2):

Becouse `float` has a precision of 15 digits.

See documentation: [float and real](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thank you ,Ya I know the precision is only upto 15 digits but I want it more than 15 digits ??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove trailing `0`s, recognize that this is now *string formatting*, not any *numeric* processing. So we'll convert it to a string and then trick `RTRIM` into doing the job for us:

```
select REPLACE(
         RTRIM(
           REPLACE(
             CONVERT(varchar(40),convert(decimal(38,35),'1.2069'))
           ,'0',' '))
       ,' ','0')
```

As I said in a comment though, it's usually more appropriate to put these presentation concerns in your presentation layer, rather than doing it down in the database - especially if whatever is consuming this result set wants to work with this data numerically. In that case, leave it alone - the trailing zeroes are only their because that's how *management studio* chooses to format `decimal`s for display.

Comment: @Raghubenten This works for what you asked and is correct, but if you are going to do mathematical operations using the results of this then your performance is going to be extremely bad.  You should very much consider the advice given to you about doing things in the presentation layer.

Comment: Thank You Damien ,The answer is perfect and what ever we do at last it when the default data structure is decimal it will pad the zeroes.